# iPhone 4s UIWebView mimic iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

How could I configure a UIWebView across all iPhones, so that all websites it navigates to would think that this is an iPhone 6s? (Something like user agent I guess?)

Thanks

Edward

**EDIT:**

This question is not about HOW to change the user agent, but WHAT VALUE should the user agent be changed to in order to make a UIWebView behave like it does on iPhone 6s across all iPhones.

Also, this question is not restrained to user agent, any other answer that would achieve this behaviour could be accepted.